# Definition of "percentile"

Tags: mathematical-statistics, quantiles, definition

I'm now reading a [note](https://pmt.physicsandmathstutor.com/download/Biology/GCSE/Notes/Edexcel/2-Cells-and-Control/Detailed%20Notes%20-%20Topic%202%20Cells%20and%20Control%20-%20Edexcel%20Biology%20GCSE.pdf) on Biostatistics written by PMT Education, and notice the following sentences in Section 2.7:

> A baby born at the 50th percentile for mass is heavier than 50% of babies.
>   A baby born at the 25th percentile for mass is heavier than 75% of babies.
>   A baby born at the 75th percentile for mass is heavier than 25% of babies.

But as I know, a baby born at the 25th percentile for mass should be heavier than 25% of babies. Is there a special definition of "percentile" in this field, or I misunderstand the sentences as a non-native speaker?

Comment: Your understanding is correct. Especially in Biomedicine percentile descriptors are following the basic idea of left to right. I worked with people from WHO in the past, saying: "*A baby born at the 75th percentile for mass is heavier than 25% of babies.*" would probably make them think I am statistically illiterate.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

While the definition of percentiles given by [Stephen Kolassa](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/1352/stephan-kolassa) is technically correct in statistical theory (the best kind of correct?), this is an issue where there is a lot of variation in practice --- some people refer to percentiles with the highest percentile as the maximum, but others flip it over so that the highest percentile is the minimum.  In the latter case people will sometimes talk about someone being in the 5th percentile when they are in the *top* five percent, rather than the *bottom* five percent.  Sometimes they will say this explicitly (e.g., John Smith is in the top 5th percentile for shot-put distance), but sometimes they won't specify this clearly.  For this reason, it is always important to clarify with the reader/speaker which way around they are defining the percentiles.  (In the absence of any specification to the contrary, they should really use the standard statistical definition.)

Also, I disagree with Stephen on one point.  I doubt this is a typographical error.  More likely, the writer of the document is simply speaking of percentiles in the second sense I have described, which while not technically correct, is nonetheless quite common.  I don't really regard this as an "error" so much as a non-standard use of the term, which is excusable if it is explained.  Here is [an example](https://graphics.wsj.com/what-percent/) of the reversed use of "percentiles" in an article on income levels in the *Wall Street Journal*.  (Most instances of reversal of the percentages occur in the context of discussions of wealth/income levels.  Though it is much less common than the technically correct usage, it occurs commonly enough that you need to be careful to check the meaning.)  Here is a [follow-up question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/416804/) where I seek examples of this reversed practice.

Comment: This is interesting but implausible: growth charts are standard stuff.  I haven't ever seen the definition of percentiles reversed there.  See https://www.cdc.gov/growthcharts/who/boys_weight_head_circumference.htm for a WHO chart, for instance.  Thus, I would find your explanation more credible if you could exhibit some instances of the reversed percentiles in actual use (preferably by some recognizable authority and not just, say, a school teacher or Web blogger).

Comment: I agree with @whuber. I have never seen the practice you refer to. "Top five percent" to refer to someone at or above the 95th percentile, yes, but "at the 5th percentile" to refer to the same someone, no. Do you have any examples of this use?

Comment: @Stephen: Well you've both seen it at least once, in the quoted section in the question.  So that is one data point of evidence in favour of this practice existing.  I don't think it is the kind of thing you are likely to see in authoritative sources, precisely because those sources tend to check the technical meaning.  However, I have seen this reversing done informally (arguably by mistake, but still sufficiently common that it is important to check).

Comment: In discussions of wealth/income, it is not unusual for sources to refer to the top X% of wealth/income, and in such cases, it is also not uncommon for them to drop the reference to the top and just say "the 1%" or "the 10%".  [Here](https://www.cnbc.com/2018/11/01/how-much-money-you-need-to-be-part-of-the-1-percent-worldwide.html) is an example of an article about "the global 1%" where you have to read three paragraphs in before they specify that they are talking about the *top* 1%.  This reversal of percentile reference is fairly common in discussions of wealth/income.

Comment: Here is another example from the [Wall Street Journal](https://graphics.wsj.com/what-percent/), where the graph lists the income percentiles in reverse, while referring to them as "percentiles".

Comment: Appealing to a solecism that motivated the question is scarcely convincing!  One could argue that the WSJ's reversal is special, given that the context was already established by the focus on the "top 1%" introduced by Romney and Clinton a few years ago--but nevertheless it's an authority and a good supporting example (+1).

Comment: It is convincing as a counterpoint to Stephen's assertion that he has "never seen the practice".  I found the WSJ article in about two minutes of Google searching, so I doubt it is that special.  I recall seeing this same thing several times before, probably also in the context of discussion of wealth/income inequality.  Moreover, it doesn't matter if the *cause* of the reversal is common reference to "the 1%" (which was popularised earlier in the Occupy movement) - the point is that this practice exists, and is not so rare that you can ignore it (or consider it a typographical error).

Comment: @Ben: thank you. (Incidentally, if you use "@Stephan", not "@Stephen", I'll be notified.) I concede your point. However, I'd like to point out that this usage typically involves "the 1%", rarely "the 1% *percentile*".

Comment: @Stephan: Oops - sorry to have misspelled your name!  I agree that that is more common.

Comment: I wanted to down-vote this but I refrained because of your other answers. WSJ is not exactly AoS when it comes to the interpretation of statistical findings. The use of the "1%er" as a persona; descriptor is more to do with evoking the emotion of  "Woah! This person is so different from us" rather than "Woah, this person is making more than 99% of us". It clearly aims to a [framing effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Framing_effect_(psychology)).

Comment: Regarding notifications, it is good practice to use autocomplete for that reason.

Comment: @whuber In the hydrology world, flow percentiles are commonly described as the 'percentage of time that flow is exceeded', so a 95th percentile flow is a low flow - its exceeded 95% of the time.  A 1% flow is a high flow, it's only exceeded 1% of the time. [EPA of Ireland](https://www.epa.ie/water/wm/hydrometrics/data/).  However use varies, [USGS](https://help.waterdata.usgs.gov/faq/surface-water/what-is-a-percentile) makes a distinction between percentile and 'percent exceedance'.

Comment: @Tony Thank you for that example.  I tend to follow the USGS (whose approach is adopted by other agencies like the USEPA).

Answer (score 16):

This is just a typo in the document. Your understanding of [percentiles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percentile) is correct.

Comment: For a broad definition of "typo".

Comment: The text goes on to say: _Being in a high percentile (e.g 90th percentile or higher) can indicate a health problem._  It's not a typo - the author is either mistaken or for some reason uses growth charts that are backwards.

Comment: Or, while admittedly very confusing, the surrounding context of the snippet ranks weight on an inverse scale. For example, the 90th percentile of 100m runners take _less_ time to run 100m than 90% of runners. The surrounding context might make such an interpretation clearer, e.g. when focusing on the severity of being underweight: severity goes up as weight goes down. If the severity is the main focus, it makes sense to sort it by severity (and thus inversely by weight); similar to how you sort track runners by performance (and inversely by time taken to complete the run).